# sencha panel overwrites what I am trying to place underneath it. datePicker and comboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, datepicker

I would like to place a comboBox underneath a datePicker however I manage to overwrite the datePicker with my comboBox when I place it inside a container. The datePicker is set to a panel and in Hbox layout, I've tried to change this to a vBox layout but this hasn't helped. Is there a way around this.

Here is my code:

```
..........................
items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'comboBox',
                fieldLabel: 'Choose Calendar',
                reference: 'chooseCalendar',
                editable: false,
                displayField: 'title',
                valueField: 'title',
                queryMode: 'local'
               }]
      }],
      datePickerCfg: {
              reference: 'datePicker',
              flex: 3,
             },
 ........................
```

datePicker is inside a constructor function in another file

```
 ........................
    layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},
constructor: function(config) {
    var newConfig = {
            items: config.items || []
        },
        datePicker = {
            xtype: 'datepicker'
        },
        checkBoxes = {
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup'
        };
    if (config.datePickerCfg) {
        datePicker = Ext.apply(datePicker, config.datePickerCfg);
        newConfig.items.push(datePicker);
    }
    checkBoxes = Ext.apply(checkBoxes, config.checkBoxes);
    newConfig.items.push(checkBoxes);

    this.callParent([Ext.apply(newConfig, config)]);
```

Comment: Can you add a sencha [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) to help you better?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine found a way to do this before I could, grrr. But here it is...

```
datePickerPanelCfg: {
            xtype: 'container',
            reference: 'datePickerPanelRef',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datepicker'
            }, {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Choose Calendar',
                    reference: 'chooseCalendar',
                    editable: false,
                    bind: {
                        store: '{calendars}'
                    },
                    displayField: 'title',
                    valueField: 'title',
                    queryMode: 'local'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'colorpicker',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    reference: 'colorPickerRef',
                    listeners: {
                        'select': 'colorPicker'
                    }
                 }]
              }]
```

the file with the constructor has the following code added to it

```
layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},
constructor: function(config) {
    var newConfig = {
            items: config.items || []
        },
        calendarPanel = {
            xtype: 'calendarpanel'
        },
        datePickerPanel = {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            border: 1,
            style: {
                borderColor: '#000000',
                borderStyle: 'solid',
                borderWidth: '1px'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datepicker'
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup'
            }, {
                xtype: 'container'
            }]

        };
    if (config.datePickerCfg) {
        datePicker = Ext.apply(datePicker, config.datePickerCfg);
        newConfig.items.push(datePicker);
    }

    datePickerPanel = Ext.apply(datePickerPanel, config.datePickerPanelCfg);
    newConfig.items.push(datePickerPanel);

    calendarPanel = Ext.apply(calendarPanel, config.calendarPanelCfg);
    newConfig.items.push(calendarPanel);

    this.callParent([Ext.apply(newConfig, config)]);
```